# IRS letter received after response due date

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

Today (January 12, 2019), I received a letter from the IRS dated December 10, 2018 (I live in Germany). The letter has a "response due date" of January 9, 2019.

Obviously, I wasn't able to reply to the letter by the due date. What are my options for dealing with this now? Does the fact the government has been shutdown for several weeks now make any difference to my situation?

Comment: Was this mailed to your German address, or to a US address and forwarded? At least some notices that affect your legal rights are automatically extended if IRS _knows_ you are outside the US, e.g. Statutory Notice Of Deficiency normally allows 90 days to petition the Tax Court but 150 days if outside US, although I don't know of any with a normal 30 days that do so.

Comment: Yes, it was mailed directly to my German address (I don't have a US address). The letter has a stamp from "Key Mail UK Limited" (www.keymailuk.com), so it was sent from the UK. It is a "Letter 692".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply ignore the 'response-due date' and respond now.
Probably they will not care about the delay. If they really do, you can still bring the argument of the mail delay.

The shutdown has formally no impact on due dates, but it makes it quite sure that nobody will look at your answerfor weeks anyway.